# Debugging Traefik when the Site Cannot Be Reached from outside Company's Intranet

Tags: docker-compose, traefik, intranet

Using `docker-compose` I have deployed a web application that uses `Traefik` as the reverse proxy, listening on port 80. This works without problem when I'm inside my company's intranet. Outside of the intranet, however, I get a 'site cannot be reached' response. Pinging the address from outside shows that the address is reachable and port 80 is open.

I've also tried to use `segments` in my `Traefik` configuration to route both the internal and external hostname I have been provided but this has no effect:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  test:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.foo.frontend.rule: "Host:${HOSTNAME};PathPrefixStrip:/test"
        traefik.bar.frontend.rule: "Host:${EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME};PathPrefixStrip:/test"
        traefik.port: 80
    networks:
      - frontend
  ...
```

I have configured the access logs to see if my requests are reaching `Traefik`, can anyone advise me what I should be looking for and how to filter the huge amount of text produced to find it? This is my `Traefik` setup configuration:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:alpine
    command: |-
      --entryPoints="Name:http Address::80"
      --entryPoints="Name:https Address::443 TLS"
      --defaultentrypoints="http,https"
      --acme 
      --acme.acmelogging="true"
      --acme.domains="${HOSTNAME}"
      --acme.domains="${EXTERNAL_HOSTNAME}"      
      --acme.email="${ACME_EMAIL}"
      --acme.entrypoint="https"
      --acme.httpchallenge
      --acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint="http"
      --acme.storage="/opt/traefik/acme.json"
      --acme.onhostrule="true"
      --docker
      --docker.swarmmode
      --docker.domain="${HOSTNAME}"
      --docker.network="frontend"
      --docker.watch
      --api
      --api.statistics
      --logLevel="DEBUG"
    networks:
      - frontend
```

Comment: As there is no infos about the OS, I'll consider that you running on Linux on native host. 
So you should start by testing your machine interfaces, with wireshark. Also need to check iptables and company firewall.